# Filter column by date into Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle11g, extract

I have column with below format date:

[image]

I want to select all records after 2017.

```
Select * from table where to_char(year(schedule_date)) > '2017'
```

but is not working...

Comment: Try this `Select * from table where to_char(schedule_date, 'YYYY') > '2017'`.

Comment: thx g00dy is working

Comment: "is not working" is not the error message. I suspect if you **read** the error message, you could have worked this out for yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `schedule_date` is a `date` column (if not, why not?)  So simply do this:

```
Select * from table where schedule_date >= date '2018-01-01';
```